# passing an angular refrence into a function as a property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a controller that looks like this

```
app.controller('TrailController', function(){
    this.tab = "firstTab";

    this.setTab = function(newValue){
      this.tab = newValue;
    };

    this.isSet = function(tabName){
      return this.tab === tabName;
    };
    this.card = "not this" ;
});
```

It takes strings in the function this.setTab and assigns them to this.tab

Now I want to pass an item from an array as a property of this.setTab and I have tried to do so using the code:

```
<a  href="" ng-click="tab.setTab({{test[0]}})">
```

note: {{test[0]}} is a directive and works elsewhere on the page.
 However when I load the page the button does not work and the console log gives me the error

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.23/$parse/syntax?p0=test&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%3A%5D&p2=14&p3=tab.setTab(%7B%7Btest%7D%7D)&p4=test%7D%7D)
```

I can't really make sense of the error:

```
Syntax Error: Token 'test' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 14 of the expression [tab.setTab({{test}})] starting at [test}}].
```

Comment: can you be a bit more clear. what is test[0]?

Comment: Why can't you do `tab.setTab(test[0])` and what do you mean by `test[0] is a directive` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<a  href="" ng-click="tab.setTab(test[0])">
```

`ng-click` is a directive, therefore you don't need the double curly brackets.